# how to make same id increment with different Alphabet?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm creating user id with concat in mysql 
this is my code query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('LHPL', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 6, '0'));

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

this query will output user id like this `LHPL001` and it is increment.
it is possible to get `LHPLS001` in same table?
the pseudo code like this.

```
if set >= 10 then
LHPLS001
else
LHPL001
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get

**`SELECT MAX(id) FROM table`**

and build **if condition** accordingly before insert.

Proposed solution is to use [susbstr](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php) function and extract Id value with best `pos` parameter value = 4